# System extension is checked and greyed out

Tags: macos, big-sur

What does it mean if under `System Preferences->Security & Privacy` system software is checked and greyed out?

Are they activated by default without actually activating them in the `Security & Privacy` settings in the first place?

Let's say I only want to activate the `Karabiner` system extension (see Screenshot) but not the greyed out ones which are checked by default? How would I do that?

[image: System Software]

**Some more information:**

Executing `sudo systemextensionsctl list`

[image: System Extensions]

Here it states that e.g. GlobalProtect is `activated waiting for user`. What does this even mean?

Comment: try the `?` in the bottom right of the preference pane

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could it be that the greyed out system extensions come from apps that were installed by another user, or that your Mac is managed by an organisation?

Comment: @anki this is a joke right?

Comment: @jaume No it is not by another user, it is my personal mac with only one user account

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you using an M1 Mac?

Comment: @iTunes No, Intel CPU

Comment: @PatrickBrielmayer did you ever get this worked out?  I have the same issue but the other way around:  It's greyed out and I cannot enable it.  I need the driver operative to get a peripheral to function

Answer (score 1):

The state `activated waiting for user` means that the system extension has been loaded onto the system and ready to be enabled, however the user has not yet allowed it to be enabled.

Normally you would open `System Preferences` `>` `Security & Privacy` and in the `General` tab click the `Allow` button to enable the system extension.

After the user has allowed the extension to run, the state listed by `systemextensionsctl` should change to be `activated enabled`.

Comment: How do you check/uncheck a box if it is greyed out.  There is no "normally" when this situation has occurred.  I had it happen to me tonight.  Reinstalling the software does nothing.